# ldap_search fails when using extensible match in filter

Tags: php, ldap

My ldap_search is failing with a protocol error if I use an extensible match in the filters. Here's the relevant code:

```
$conn = ldap_connect(SERVER, PORT);
ldap_bind($conn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PW);            

$filter = "(&(whatever=*)(uid=something)(!(ou:dn:=other)))";
$s = ldap_search($conn, BASE_DN, $filter);
if (ldap_errno($conn) != 0) {
    echo "Error: " + ldap_error($conn);
    exit();
}
$res = ldap_get_entries($conn, $s);
var_dump($res);
exit();
```

if I use instead:

```
$filter = "(&(whatever=*)(uid=something))";
```

it works OK. If I use ldapsearch from the command line with the extensible match part it works fine, so it's not a ldap server version problem.

I also tried to include

```
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

and

```
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 2);
```

and none worked. I'm using PHP 7.0.28.

Anyone has any idea what's happening ?

**Edit**

Responding to @heiglandreas:

```
user@mycomp:~$ ldapsearch -VV
ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch  (Ubuntu) (May 30 2017 19:20:53) $
    buildd@lgw01-18:/build/openldap-JXEADB/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/clients/tools
    (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20442)
```

output from php_info:

```
LDAP Support    enabled
RCS Version     $Id: cec20da3ccaa477662b8667bef021291fb5bf6f4 $
Total Links     0/unlimited
API Version     3001
Vendor Name     OpenLDAP
Vendor Version  20442
SASL Support    Enabled

Directive       Local Value     Master Value
ldap.max_links  Unlimited       Unlimited
```

Responding to jwilleke:

```
vendorName    389 Project
vendorVersion 389-Directory/1.2.11.15 B2016.194.1549
```

but I'm sure it supports the filter as ldapseach with extensible match from command line works fine.

Comment: What LDAP-library are you using on the command line? Which version? And can you post what phpinfo() says about the ldap-extension?

Comment: Which LDAP Server Implementation are you using? Does the LDAP Server support the extensible match filter?